Constructor parameter is null until parent is not initialized
Look at the following code:
abstract class A {

    init {
        f()
    }

    abstract fun f()
}

class B(val p: () -> Unit) : A() {

    override fun f() {
        try {
            p()
        } catch (c: Throwable) {
            println(c)
        }
    }
}

val b = B {
    println("p() called")
}

Expecting p() called will be printed, actual result is NPE:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0.invoke()" because "this.p" is null

Could you please explain, why can't I access child constructor parameter from parent's constructor? And how can I deal with this?

The superclass part of the class has to be fully constructed before the extra stuff defined in the subclass. Therefore, you must never call any open/abstract functions or properties from a constructor because they could be referencing things that have not been initialized yet.
For you to be able to call this function in the superclass constructor, you would need to make it a constructor parameter in the superclass. The subclass can pass it to the superclass there.
But the example is maybe too generalized to really be able to suggest an applicable alternative to whatever it is you are trying to do.
